# How do you install blocking in a straight line?

Tags: framing, carpentry

When installing blocking that is staggered, you can end-nail it. But what about when it's important for the blocking to be in a straight line?

For example, when you want to support butted-edges of sheet goods.

How should the blocking be fastened?

Comment: what kind of sheet goods you talking about over framing lunber?

Comment: In this case, 3/4" T&G Plywood subfloor over 2x joists.

Answer (score 4):

Toe nailing is usually the easiest (provided you're using an nail gun).

If you want to get fancy, you could end-nail every other one, then use L-brackets for the ones in between (nail the bracket to the blocking so that and then nail the bracket into the studs):

```
                     |  |
                    +|  |
                    ||  |
                    ||  |
               +----+|  |
    +---------------+|  |
    |               ||  |
    +---------------+|  |
                     |  |
                     |  |
```

Comment: Either I should have said "no nail gun" or I should buy a nail gun!

Comment: @Jay you should ABSOLUTELY buy a nail gun! That's the entire reason for owning a house! ;) (On a more serious note, I took me years before I 'saw the light' and caved to get a compressor and nail gun set up. It really is a much better way to work.)

Comment: I don't live in a house, ha ha. My friend is storing a compressor with me, so I'm 1/2-way there. Hmm.

Comment: If you had a nail gun, you could BUILD A HOUSE! C'mon man, work with me here...I'm trying to help find you a good excuse to get one. ;)

Comment: @DA01 can I quote you on the reason to own a house?  My wife isn't convinced...

Comment: You could also toe screw it with deck nails.

Answer (score 1):

You could put a double block in every other stud bay.Stagger the blocks so you can get good use of your new nailgun.Then go back and nail a second block (more use of the new tool) on top of the lower block to give you a nice straight nailing surface.